# python. finding largest integer in string

Tags: string, python-2.7

Write the function `largestNumber(text)` that takes a string of text and returns the largest int value that occurs within that text, or `None` if no such value occurs.

For example:

```
largestNumber("I saw 3 dogs, 17 cats, and 14 cows!")
```

returns 17 (the int value 17, not the string "17").

and

```
largestNumber("One person ate two hot dogs!")
```

returns `None` (the value `None`, not the string `"None"`).

I tried using `isdigit` function to separate out integer but how can I compare string?

Comment: Duplicate of the deleted question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499549)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a *regex*, and then `max` and `map` functions:

```
result = [e for e in re.split("[^0-9]", "I saw 3 dogs, 17 cats, and 14 cows!") if e != '']

# list 'result' elements are strings: ['3', '17', '14'], so we use map(int, list) to get integers
print max(map(int, result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
def largestNumber(in_str):
    l=[int(x) for x in in_str.split() if x.isdigit()]
    return max(l) if l else None
```

First you split `in_str` based on space () with `split()` to get a list.

The 'numbers' in this list are identified using `isdigit()` and converted to integers using `int()`.

These numbers are stored in `l` as a list.

The expression

```
max(l) if l else None
```

will give maximum value in l if `l` is not empty and otherwise `None`.

---

```
print(largestNumber("I saw 3 dogs, 17 cats, and 14 cows!"))
```

gives

```
17
```

and

```
print(largestNumber("One person ate two hot dogs!"))
```

gives

```
None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findLargestNumber(text):
    front = -1
    li = []

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if front == -1:
            if text[i].isdigit():
                front = i
            else:
               continue
        else:
            if text[i].isdigit():
               continue
            else:
                li.append(int(text[front:i+1]))
                front = -1

return max(li)

print findLargestNumber('I saw 3 dogs, 17 cats, and 14 cows!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Another solution:

```
def findLargestNumber(text):
    ls = list()
    for w in text.split():
        try:
            ls.append(int(w))
        except:
            pass
    try:
        return max(ls)
    except:
        return None

print findLargestNumber('I saw 3 dogs, 17 cats, and 14 cows!')
print findLargestNumber('I saw ')
```

Output:

```
17
None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def extractmax(str1):
    nums=re.findall("\d+",str1)
    return max(nums)
```

`\d+` is used to look for a decimal or number with length greater than one, it is appended into the array `nums` finally maximum value from `nums` if generated.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, and it works great!
Increment number in the string and then print out the max number in string

> 1. import re

```
import re
```

> 2. Increase number in string

```
name = "name 1"
number = re.search(r'\d+', str(name))

if number:
rx = r'(?<!\d){}(?!\d)'.format(number.group())
    prefix = re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1), name)
    print(prefix)
```

> Instead of just printing this row directly "re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1), name)"

> Store it in a variable, in my case prefix
>
> That's because you will get the updated value in the string and not the original

> Store incremented variable "name" into a list

```
li = [int(prefix[5:])]
print("Largest name", max(li))
```

Keep in mind that index 5 is where the number is starting, you may need to adjust it depending on the string length

You can try to make 2 variables to see if the max method is working properly